# Cythonize list of ndarrays to indirect_contiguous

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

I want to cythonize a list of ndarrays (with different sizes) to speed up the performance of a function. A data structure of the type [:: view.indirect_contiguous,::1] seems the way to go, creating a contiguous array of pointers linked to contiguous memoryview of different sizes, but it is not clear to me how to setup it properly. How do I do it up and how do I access its elements?

In the following MWE I put the simple sum of elements just to test the access of the elements (I am not interested in speeding it up with other formulations)

```
from typing import List
import numpy as np

def python_foo(array_list: List[np.ndarray]):
  list_len = len(array_list)
  results = np.zeros((list_len,1), dtype=np.int8)
  # prints few elements and sum them
  print(array_list[0][0], array_list[0][1], array_list[1][0], array_list[1][1])
  for k in range(list_len):
    results[k] = np.sum(array_list[k])
  return results


import cython
cimport numpy as np
from cython cimport view
from libc.stdio cimport printf

DTYPE = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t

def cython_foo(array_list: List[np.ndarray]):
  cdef int list_len = len(array_list)
  cdef DTYPE_t[::view.indirect_contiguous, ::1] my_mem_view
  # (1) - how do I assign the ndarrays to my_mem_view? 

  # prints few elements and sum them
  # (2) - how do I access the elements of my_mem_view? is this correct?
  printf("%f %f %f %f\n", my_mem_view[0,0], my_mem_view[0,1], my_mem_view[1,0], my_mem_view[1,1])
  cdef DTYPE_t results[list_len] = {0}
  cdef int k
  cdef int n
  for k in range(list_len):
    for n in range(array_list[k].size) # should I also create an array of lengths?
      results[k] += my_mem_view[k,n] 
  # BONUS question: I probably need to convert results to Python objects (list, ndarrays), right?
  return results
```

Comment: buffer protocol doesn't support jagged arrays - all lengths should be the same.

Comment: If I get it correctly, you are saying that DTYPE_t[::view.indirect_contiguous, ::1] cannot manage memviews with different lengths? Is that right? At the same time, in C it makes sense to have an array of pointers to arrays of different sizes. Do you have any idea on how to do it in cython to handle a list of ndarrays?

Comment: It seems like "list" might be the correct type. When you need to operate on an individual element then you can type it if helpful.

Comment: But if I use a list I still need the gil, while if I completely cythonize the data I will avoid it

Comment: Does it matter if you need the GIL? Or can you release the GIL as you process each memoryview?

Comment: I need to release the GIL as soon as the data structures are setup. The function operates on all the memoryviews from the list of ndarrays together, and will be called on multiple lists (hence the nogil).

Comment: I don't think the data structure you want exists, unfortunately.

Comment: @DavidW say that I define (in C) an array of pointers, and these are linked to the data of the ndarray (which I convert to contiguous). Say I also save the shape, strides, ecc of the ndarray for a correct access of the items. What would it be the downside of this approach?

Comment: The downside is that you have to keep track of reference counting yourself (i.e. ensure that your numpy data pointers remain valid) and also handle all the indexing manually. It should work though (but may turn out not to be worth the effort)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution that uses a temporary memoryview to get the pointer to the data. If anyone finds a better, cleaner or quicker answer please let me know.

I wonder if I got the memory management right or if something is missing.

```
# indirect_contiguous.pyx
cimport numpy as np
from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Malloc, PyMem_Free
DTYPE = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t

def cython_foo(array_list: List[np.ndarray]):
  cdef int list_len = len(array_list)

  # (1) 
  cdef DTYPE_t ** my_mem_view = <DTYPE_t **> PyMem_Malloc(list_len * sizeof(DTYPE_t *))
  cdef int idx
  cdef DTYPE_t[:] item_1 # cdef not allowed in conditionals
  cdef DTYPE_t[:,:] item_2
  cdef DTYPE_t[:,:,:] item_3
  # ... other cdef for DTYPE_t[...] up to dimension 8 - the maximum allowed for a memoryview
  cdef int *array_len = <int *> PyMem_Malloc(list_len * sizeof(int))
  for idx in range(list_len):
    if len(array_list[idx].shape) == 1:
      item_1 = np.ascontiguousarray(array_list[idx], dtype=DTYPE)
      my_mem_view[idx] = <DTYPE_t *> &item_1[0]
    elif len(array_list[idx].shape) == 2:
      item_2 = np.ascontiguousarray(array_list[idx], dtype=DTYPE)
      my_mem_view[idx] = <DTYPE_t *> &item_2[0, 0]
    elif len(array_list[idx].shape) == 3:
      item_3 = np.ascontiguousarray(array_list[idx], dtype=DTYPE)
      my_mem_view[idx] = <DTYPE_t *> &item_3[0, 0, 0]
    # ... other elif for DTYPE_t[:,:,:] up to dimension 8
    array_len[idx] = array_list[idx].size

  # prints few elements and sum them
  # (2)
  printf("%f %f %f %f\n", my_mem_view[0][0], my_mem_view[0][1], my_mem_view[1][0], my_mem_view[1][1])
  cdef DTYPE_t *results = <DTYPE_t *> PyMem_Malloc(list_len * sizeof(DTYPE_t))
  cdef int k
  cdef int n
  for k in range(list_len):
    results[k] = 0
    for n in range(array_len[k]):
      results[k] += my_mem_view[k][n]

  py_results = []
  for k in range(list_len):
    py_results.append(results[k])

  # free memory
  PyMem_Free(my_mem_view)
  PyMem_Free(array_len)
  PyMem_Free(results)

  return py_results
```

Testing the speed with

```
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="indirect_contiguous.python_foo([np.random.random((100,100,100)), np.random.random((100,100))])",
                    setup="import numpy as np; import indirect_contiguous; ", number=100))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="indirect_contiguous.cython_foo([np.random.random((100,100,100)), np.random.random((100,100))])",
                    setup="import numpy as np; import indirect_contiguous; ", number=100))
```

I get a small improvement (1.45 sec. vs 1.42 sec.) of the 2-3%, possibly due to the fact that I am just doing sum of elements (for which numpy is already optimized).

Comment: @DavidW I have proposed a solution, but as you say I have to deal with the indexing manually. Do you think there is a way to get around the using of item_1, item_2, ... and using a single variable or maybe a way to link directly to numpy data?

Comment: You don't look to be freeing `array_len`. Numpy has a `data` variable containing the pointer, however using that (and your current code) make the assumption that the arrays are contiguous without enforcing it. This seems to be falling into the classic trap that you want something that is both typed (for speed) but also general enough to handle any type of array, and that doesn't really exist.

Comment: You are right, I have forgotten PyMem_Free(array_len) - now added. The array pointed by the elements in my_mem_view are freed by Python memory management, right? Also, do you think it is enough to make the array contiguous with np.ascontiguousarray befone assign item_1, item_2, ... ?

Comment: Yes, the arrays pointed to by the elements in `my_mem_view` should be managed by Python. `np.ascontiguousarray` should be fine provided you keep at least one reference to the contiguous array it returns. If you don't keep a reference to it then these arrays will be freed and your pointer will be invalid.